# how do you translate the word Patron if the word is used for a person in a university

Tags: meaning

I'm translating the Welcome Guide of my uni, Nicolaus Copernicus University.
There is a "Patron" section in which Nicolaus Copernicus is introduced, I wonder how can i translate this word, I actually don't even know how to define patron here.
Copernicus is a meaningful figure of this uni, but in what way should i understand the word Patron?

Comment: I would say the choice is yours.  Usually, it depends on whether we are using the noun as a Title or as just another noun.  So, for example, when I write that "Saint Cecelia is the patron saint of music", you can see that I have used a capital 'S' for "Saint", whereas I use lower case for the fact that she is saint.  So, Queen Elizabeth II is the queen of Great Britain.

Comment: Is "patron" being used in the sense of "patron saint", or in the sense of "financial benefactor"?

Comment: Is this a question about how to translate the **Polish** word *patron* into English? If so, it needs to be explained why consulting the standard Polish-English dictionaries is not sufficient to answer it.

Comment: It is not quite the usual meaning but I suggest: "[**Champion**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/champion) – Nicolaus Copernicus was the inspiration for the university, which bears his name to this day."

Comment: @ Hot Licks no, there's no context, the Patron section is a sub-section of "What should i know about NCU? and then the "Patron" Copernicus is introduced.

Comment: @ jsw29 no, it's an English guide, and i have translate it into Chinese. i was thinking about the English meaning.

Comment: Thoroughly confused now: you are translating which language to which language? The title asks "how do you translate the word Patron?"

Comment: The English guide is not using the word *patron* in English properly, probably because it's the translation of a Polish word.

Comment: @Angyang - You will have to do some research to understand what Copernicus's role was.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the question, as stated, is somewhat confusing, let me first articulate my understanding of the problem. An institution named *Nicolaus Copernicus University* has issued a document, in English, in which Nicolaus Copernicus is referred to as the **patron** of the University. The OP is puzzled by that use of the  word, and seeks its explanation, for the purpose of translating it into another language.

The OP is rightly puzzled by this use of the word, because it is indeed nonstandard. Normally, a patron of an institution is somebody who **supports** it in some significant way, typically a major donor. (Occasionally, the word can be used even if the support is largely nominal, as long as it ceremonially significant, but that use of the word still depends on the idea that the patron somehow supports the institution.) Given that Nicolaus Copernicus lived five centuries ago, he clearly cannot do anything to support a present-day institution.

What could have then been on the minds of the people who used the word *patron* in that document? The most reasonable hypothesis is they have been led astray by the well known phrase *patron saint*. Patron saints are patrons in the standard sense of that word: according to the relevant religious beliefs, they support whatever they are patron saints of. According to these beliefs, they continue to exist and exercise their support, in spite of having left their earthly lives long ago. The authors of the university's document probably wanted to encourage their audience to think of Nicolaus Copernicus as **something like the patron saint** of the university. They, however, couldn't have called him its patron saints because he is, obviously, not a saint. So they dropped the word *saint* from the phrase *patron saint*, and called him simply its patron. The result is, however, awkward, as a the meaning of that word requires the person  in some way support the university, which Copernicus cannot do.

Nicolaus Copernicus can certainly be called a **namesake** of the university (as has been pointed out by Mr. Shor), but that does not by itself convey an idea of a particularly strong connection between the two.

Comment: The reason that Nicolaus Copernicus is called the *patron* of the university is that he is called the "patron" in Polish. I don't know any Polish, but if you look at the [Polish Wikipedia page,](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniwersytet_Miko%C5%82aja_Kopernika_w_Toruniu) it says "Patron: Mikołaj Kopernik".

Comment: this is definitely the answer that i want, and i think everyone wants to see it; it's indeed a really good answer, even though i don't know if the author of the document really suggested patron saint, your assumption makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Titular Patron**

> **titular**
>
> adjective
>
> existing or being such in title only; nominal; having the title but
> none of the associated duties, powers, etc.:
>
> the titular head of the company.
>
> from whom or which a title or name is taken:
>
> His titular Saint is Michael.
> https://www.dictionary.com/browse/titular

Answer (score -2):

Edit:
Since people say that he could not possibly have supported the university since he is dead. I am changing this to Distinguished Figurehead of the university.

Comment: This is indeed what the word *patron* normally means in English, but it only shows that *patron* can hardly be the right word for the OP's purposes, given that Copernicus lived five centuries ago.

Comment: @jsw29 He supported the university in the past so he was still a supporter. Right? Everyone knows that he is dead. Unless you want to change it to Former Supporter.

Comment: Copernicus is actually the ***namesake*** of the university, not a supporter. It was founded after he died.

Comment: Nicolaus Copernicus University seems to have been founded in 1945.  Its namesake died in 1543.

Comment: *Figurehead* is even worse than *supporter*. Leland Stanford was a founder and supporter of Stanford University, but he was never its figurehead, and even now that he's dead, he still isn't.

Comment: @PeterShor, yes, *namesake* is an apt term to use for Copernicus' relationship to this institution, but it seems that the OP is looking for something stronger, some word that will convey the idea that the university is not only named after Copernicus, but that its activities are somehow inspired by the values that were manifested in Copernicus' life.